# Translate with google via browser with php

Tags: php, translation, google-translate

is it possible to translate a php string via browser using the method GET?

I found this working in VBA:

```
 Sub TranslateCell()
    Dim getParam As String, trans As String, translateFrom As String, translateTo As String
    translateFrom = "en"
    translateTo = "es"
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    getParam = ConvertToGet(ActiveCell.Value)
    URL = "https://translate.google.pl/m?hl=" & translateFrom & "&sl=" & translateFrom & "&tl=" & translateTo & "&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=" & getParam
    objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.Send ("")
    If InStr(objHTTP.ResponseText, "div dir=""ltr""") > 0 Then
        trans = RegexExecute(objHTTP.ResponseText, "div[^""]*?""ltr"".*?>(.+?)</div>")
        ActiveCell.Value = Clean(trans)
    Else
        MsgBox ("Error")
    End If
End Sub
```

But, would it be possible to make this in PHP. Would this be possible?

Comment: found [this](https://github.com/Stichoza/google-translate-php) in github

Comment: You can use method `file_get_contents()` if it's a simple GET request or `CURL` if it needs some additional header info or POST instead of GET

Comment: @Hamid, `file_get_conents()` supports POST: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#108309